# Is it possible to use app.UseExceptionHandler without it being global?

Tags: asp.net-core

As per the title, I want to place the following line within Startup.cs

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/My/Custom/Route/ErrHandler");
```

, but I understand it to have a global effect on ALL Controllers, and action methods.

How can I make it apply to only specific Controllers that I choose?

[ Or to rephrase the question, is there another way to do what I described, I don't really have to use app.UseExceptionHandler if it's not required ]

Comment: Have a look at [Exception Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0#exception-filters).

Comment: @KirkLarkin Yes, thank you. I remembered about them soon after I posted.

Comment: @KirkLarkin would you please write it as an answer, so I can accept it. I know it's the simplest question and answer ever, but rather than delete it, it may be helpful to somebody else.